# CASE WHEN in magento getCollection

Tags: mysql, magento

I need to execute following query in magneto getcollection, It is working query.

```
SELECT *
FROM `subscribers-members-old`
WHERE `ZIP` LIKE '9%'
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN `ZIP` = '9305' THEN 1 
        WHEN `ZIP` LIKE '9%' THEN 2 ELSE 3 END
```

but I am not sure how to add case when conditions in magento collection, can you please anyone help me to sort out this.

currently my magento query is

```
$collections = Mage::getModel('storelocator/storelocator')->getCollection()

                ->setStoreId($storeId)

                ->addFieldToFilter('status', 1);

$collections->addFieldToFilter('zipcode', array(
                array('where' => $zipcode), 
                array('like' => $trimzip[0].'%')

                ));
```

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
$collections->getSelect()->order
(new Zend_Db_Expr("CASE WHEN `ZIP` = '9305' THEN 1 
       WHEN `ZIP` LIKE '9%' THEN 2 
       ELSE 3 END"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$collections->getSelect()->order
("CASE WHEN `ZIP` = '9305' THEN 1 
       WHEN `ZIP` LIKE '9%' THEN 2 
       ELSE 3 END")
```